# Polyfiller is not working in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: angularjs, webshim

I followed the [Webshim](https://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/) demo and insert date field on html instead of `datetimepicker` due to browser compatibility issue.

In Mozilla Firefox browser , the `PolyFiller` is working fine when firslty the `main.gsp` page is loaded, the date input working fine. But the problem occurs when I route (using angular) to other html page and come back to  `callRecorded.html` , then I find only input field disabled, there is no `PloyFiller` date has been shown. I don't understand why this show such behavior.

For client side I am using `angularJS` and use `$routeProvider` to route the html pages in my application, may be that cause the problem. The following code describe the way I am using `Pollyfiller` in my application:-

**Main.gsp (Groovy server page)**

```
<asset:javascript src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"/>
<asset:javascript src="plugins/js-webshim/minified/polyfiller.js"/>
```

**callRecorded.html**

```
<label>Start Date</label>
<input type="date"  data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
```

**App.js**

```
when('/callsRecorded/:callStatus', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/evr/callsRecorded.html'
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.